# Gridview doesn't work under Listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I write gridView Code under listView but GridView's scrolling does not work under listview.

```
Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
  children: [
    GridViewBuilder(), //explicit class
  ],
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap with container to gridview.

And you should give a specific height

```
Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
          child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                  maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                  childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 20),
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(index.toString()),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: I used both properties(shrinkwrap and physics) in GridViewBuilder() class but It still not work.

Comment: If I run GridView.builder outside ListView then It works perfectly but does not work in ListView.